# Problemas con DOMPDF y HTML

Tags: php, webforms, phpmailer, dompdf

Muy buenas, estoy reportando problemas al generar Dompdf. Resulta que en el preview de HTML, se ve de esta forma:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo envío por correo mediante PHPMailer y Dompdf, el resultado es el siguiente, donde se divide en cuatro páginas:
[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY6Ii.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El fallo puede estar dentro del bucle WHILE donde se realiza el insertado de lineas facturas. He probado comentándolo y funciona de forma correcta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro el fallo de dicho script ni nada de CSS. No entiendo el porqué me lo divide en hojas ya que debería de ser una.

```
$options = new Options();
                        $options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
                        $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

                        $context = stream_context_create([ 
                        'ssl' => [ 
                                'verify_peer' => FALSE, 
                                'verify_peer_name' => FALSE,
                                'allow_self_signed'=> TRUE 
                            ] 
                        ]);
                        $dompdf->setHttpContext($context);

                        // Se carga el codigo html
                        $dompdf->load_html($html);

                        $dompdf->set_paper(array(0,0,1200,1450));


                        // Lanzamos a render
                        $dompdf->render();
                        //$dompdf->set_base_path('dist/css/style.min.css');

                        $output = $dompdf->output();
                        $ruta = 'facturas/factura'.time().'.pdf';
                        file_put_contents($ruta, $output);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Tambien te sugiero que coloques el codigo como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: Saludos, sin duda tu pregunta es muy interesante, te sugiero agregar el codigo de como generas dicho pdf y su envio posterior para de esta manera darte una posible respuesta..!!